# How to modify multiple dataframes in rstudio?

Tags: r

I am working with multiple data frames(over 20) and I like to make a loop which add two new columns of mean value of both columns in every data frames. I like to use loop because amount of data frames can alter.

Example of data:

```
df_1:
   Width Thickness
1  1000    1
2  1500    2

df_2:
1  1200    3
2  1200    4
3  1000    2

df_3:
1  1200    3
2  1500    4


desired outcome:
df_1:
   Width Thickness mean_width mean_thick
1  1000    1           1250       1.5
2  1500    2           1250       1.5
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? Also this is a summary operation on the data, so it does not make much sense replicating the same value into all of the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the dataframes in a list based on the pattern in their name using `ls` and `mget`. We can then use `lapply` to add new columns to each dataframe

```
new_data <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'df_\\d+')), function(x) {
  x[paste0('mean_', names(x))] <- as.list(colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE))
  x
})
```

`new_data` will have list of dataframes in them, if you want the changes to be reflected in the original dataframes use `list2env` :

```
list2env(new_data, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: That is a very neat trick for making the list of dataframes and updating them in the global enviorment - thanks for sharing.

Comment: Thanks for this. The solution is elegant and just the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a list of dataframes and then applying a function over that list.

Below I'm using tidyverse's map function but this is also achievable using base R and the apply family of functions:

```
library(tidyverse)

df_list <- list(df_1, df_2, df_3)

map(df_list, mutate, mean_width = mean(Width), mean_thick = mean(Thickness))
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to create a single dataset and then do a group by operation

```
library(dplyr)   
mget(ls(pattern = 'df_\\d+')) %>%
      bind_rows(.id = 'grp') %>%
      group_by(grp) %>%
      mutate(across(everything(), mean, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "mean_{col}")) %>%
      ungroup
```